# Content keeps floating up under fixed div at top of page when using http://www.appelsiini.net/ :in-viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a page that each time a new section has the most focus, it's header goes into a fixed div at the top.  When i use the :in-viewport functions, the content floats up as well and becomes unseen.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#navmenu").hide();
});
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#pull").click(function(){$("#navmenu").toggle();});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#navmenu").click(function(){$("#navmenu").toggle();});
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#titleheader").hide();
});

$(document).scroll(function () {
/*$('.titl').hide();*/
if($('.bottomtitle').is(':in-viewport')){
$("#titleheader").hide();
} else {
$("#titleheader").show();   
}});

$(document).scroll(function () {
if($('.bottomtitle').is(':in-viewport'))
{
$(".mainthead").css({"position":"relative","margin-left":"0px"});
$('.lawnmaintenance').css("margin-top",'0em');
}
else if($('.lawnmaintenance').is(':in-viewport')){
if($('.bottomtitle').is(':in-viewport')==false){
$(".mainthead").css({"position":"fixed","top":"0px","margin-left":"4em","z-         
index":"102"});
$('.lawnmaintenance').css("margin-top",'10em');
}
}
else if($('.lawnmaintenance').is(':above-the-top'))
{
$(".mainthead").css({"position":"relative","margin-left":"0px"});
$('.lawnmaintenance').css("margin-top",'0em');
}
else {
$(".mainthead").css({"position":"relative","margin-left":"0px"});
$('.lawnmaintenance').css("margin-top",'0em');
}});

$(document).scroll(function()
{
if($('.shrub').is(':in-viewport')==false)
{
$(".treeshrub").css({"position":"static","margin-left":"0px"});
$('treediv').css('margin-top','0em');
}
else  if($('.treeshrub').is(':in-viewport'))
{
if($('.lawnmaintenance').is('.in-viewport')==false){
$(".treeshrub").css({"position":"fixed","top":"0px","left":"4em","z-        
index":"101"});
$('.treediv').css('margin-top','10em')}
}
else {
$(".treeshrub").css({"position":"static","margin-left":"0px"});
$('.treediv').css('margin-top','0em');
}}
);
</script>
```

html code

```
<!--<div class="w3-container w3-theme-l3" id="navmenu" style="height: 100vh;     
width: 100vw; position: fixed; top: 0px; z-index:99; opacity: .8;">-->

<nav class="inset" id="navmenu">
<ul id="navul">
<li class="w3-container w3-theme-i4" id="navitem"><a href="#" 
id="nava">Home</a></li><br>
<li class="w3-container w3-theme-i4" id="navitem"><a href="#"  
id="nava">About</a></li><br>
<li class="w3-container w3-theme-i4" id="navitem"><a href="#"  
id="nava">Contact</a></li><br>
</ul>
</nav>

<!--</div>-->
<div class="w3-container w3-green" style="height: 2.5em; position:fixed;  
top: 0px; z-index: 100;">
<a href="#menu" id="pull"><img id="titlepic" src="images/menu.png"  
alt="Menu" style="height:2em; margin-top: 3px;"></a>
</div>
<header id="titleheader" class="w3-container w3-theme-l3 inset"   
style="height:5em; width: 100vw; padding-right: 1em; text-align: right;   
position: fixed; top: 0px; z-index: 99;"><h1 style="font-size: 1em; margin-  
right: 1em; "><b>Magnolia Outdoor Solutions...</b></h1><h2 style=" font-
size:  .75em;">Landscape maintenance and improvement solutions for North 
Metro  Atlanta...</h2></header>
<div class="w3-image inset w3-animate-bottom" style="margin-bottom: 5px;     
border-bottom: 5px solid white;"><img class="titl" id="titleimg"   
src="images/grass.jpg" style="width: 100%; max-height: 650px;">
<div class="w3-title w3-text-white bottomtitle" id="bottom-title"><header 
class="w3-container"><h1>Magnolia Outdoor Solutions</h1><h2>Landscape 
maintenance and improvement services for North Metro Atlanta</h2></header> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="w3-row lawnmaintenance" style="margin-top: 5px;">
<div class="w3-col " style="width:70%;">
<header class="w3-container w3-theme-l3 inset servheadleft mainthead"      
style="color:white;">
<h2>Lawn Maintenance</h2></header>
<div class="w3-container">
<p>content</p>
</div></div> 
<div class="w3-col" style="width: 30%;"> <img class="picr"    
src="images/landscape.jpg" style="width: 100%;"><img class="picr"  
src="images/zoysia.jpg" style="width: 100%;"><img class="picr"   
src="images/fescue2.jpg" style="width: 100%;"><img class="picr"  
src="images/edge.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="w3-row treediv">
<div class="w3-col" style="width: 30%;"> <img class="picl"      
src="images/bush1.jpg" style="width: 100%;"><img class="picl"  src=
"images/bushes.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
</div>
<div class="w3-col " style="width:70%;">
<header class="w3-container w3-theme-l3 inset servheadright treeshrub">
<h2>Tree & Shrub Care</h2></header>
<div class="w3-container">
<p class="shrub">content content</p>
</div></div> 
</div>
```